# How to disable account expiration and mandatory change of password after it expires in linux?

Tags: linux, password

I want to change the password expiration to non expire and for that i used below command

```
[root@test-host ~]# chage -l test
Last password change                                    : password must be changed
Password expires                                        : password must be changed
Password inactive                                       : password must be changed
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0


chage -m 0 -M 99999 -I -1 -E -1 test

[root@test-host ~]# chage -l test
Last password change                                    : Jun 10, 2017
Password expires                                        : never
Password inactive                                       : never
Account expires                                         : never
Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
```

But eventhough it is now in non expire status, it is asking me to change the password.So is it anyway to disable change of existing password after expire

```
test@test-host's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Wed Jun 14 01:28:07 2017 from 
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user test.
Changing password for test.
```

Comment: Can you do `chage -M -1 test`?

Comment: tried no luck still asking to change the password

Comment: try forcing a new password with `passwd`

Comment: requirement is we should not change the current password

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

`passwd -x -1 -n -1 -w -1 ${USER}`

It may produce the same result but it could do the trick.